# How do you exclude fields in Jackson json serialisation (Scala)

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I am trying to exclude the _passthroughFields property in the example below. When I use the debugger, it looks like my `PropertyFilter` is never used. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.SerializeExceptFilter
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleFilterProvider
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{DeserializationFeature, ObjectMapper, ObjectWriter}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpec}

import scala.collection.immutable.Map

class PassthroughFieldsSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers {
  "JacksonParser" when {
    "given an Object and undesired fields" should {
      "not include those fields in the json response" in {
        trait Foo {
          def id: String
          def _passthroughFields: Map[String, String] = Map.empty
        }

        class Bar(val id: String, override val _passthroughFields: Map[String, String]) extends Foo

        val item = new Bar("abcd", Map.empty)

        val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
        mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

        val excludes = new util.HashSet[String](1)
        excludes.add("_passthroughFields")
        excludes.add("get_passthroughFields")

        val filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
          .addFilter("filter properties by name", new SerializeExceptFilter(excludes))

        val writer: ObjectWriter = mapper.writer(filters)

        val json = writer.writeValueAsString(item)
        json.contains("_passthroughFields") shouldBe false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, I ran your test scenario and it successfully passed. Why you think filter ignored?

Comment: It doesn't work when I run it. The json variable contains `{"id":"abcd","_passthroughFields":{}}` and still contains `_passthroughFields` which should be excluded. (running against jackson-module-scala 2.5.1 and scalatest 2.2.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can exclude it using something like @JsonIgnore or make the field transient.

Otherwise if you need to define it outside of the case class code (like in your example) you can do it with [Genson](http://owlike.github.io/genson/Documentation/ScalaGuide/).

```
import com.owlike.genson._
import com.owlike.genson.reflect.VisibilityFilter

// Note that if you use case classes you don't need the visibility filter stuff
// it is used to indicate that private fields should be ser/de
val genson = new GensonBuilder()
  .withBundle(ScalaBundle())
  .useFields(true, VisibilityFilter.PRIVATE)
  .exclude("_passthroughFields")
  .create()

genson.toJson(item)
```

Disclaimer: I am Gensons author.

Comment: yes the class is not under my control. It is a class generated by the scrooge-sbt-plugin (Thrift). I will give Genson a try, looks very nice - thanks!

Comment: Great, if you encounter any problems don't hesitate to report them on the mailing list or github